# Matlab 3D Volume visualization - dicom file

Tags: matlab, 3d, dicom

I am looking forward to visualize a 3D matrix into matlab from dicom files. As I am not quite familiar with matlab, i managed to get help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942251/matlab-3d-volume-visualization-and-3d-overlay):

The difference is that my matrix is not made of 1 and 0 but negative numbers that are correctly red with `imshow(dicomeread(dicomFile))`

How can I get to the same contrast but with a 3D rendering ?

My code :

```
dicomFilesZm = dir(fullfile(myDcmFolder, 'SLZ-*.dcm')); %Get files name
dicomFilesZp = dir(fullfile(myDcmFolder, 'SLZ+*.dcm')); %~

Z = dicomFilesZm(end:-1:1); % sort

dicomFilesZ = [Z ; dicomFilesZp]; % recompose final array with files name

Iz1 = fullfile(myDcmFolder, dicomFilesZ(1).name); 
v = NaN([size(dicomread(Iz1)) numel(dicomFilesZ)]); % creation of empty matrix with the good size    
for i = 1 : numel(dicomFilesZ)
    Iz = fullfile(myDcmFolder, dicomFilesZ(i).name);
    v(:,:,i) = dicomread(Iz); % fill the matrix with each image
end

p = patch( isosurface(v,0) );
isonormals(v, p)
set(p, 'FaceColor','r', 'EdgeColor','none')
daspect([1 1 1])
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for solving your problem:

1. Naively, why won't you just set `v=v+min(v(:))`  so the image will scale from zero to a different maximum value?
2. Why won't `isosurface(V,isovalue)` with negative isovlaue solve this issue for you?
   Or if you want loop over isovalues from (-n:step_size:m) to get the dynamic range you want (with some `alpha(0.2)` to see the layers you want)

Comment: 1 : I just started with matlab, i barely understand what your lines exactly do although I get what it is supposed to do, thank you, i will know from now.

2: I tried to put -1 as isovalue in isosurface, but still my result is black and white :/
I was thinking that if imshow can have a nice contrast, why not isosurface ?

I could provide more info like a part of the matrix v.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: isonormals(v, p) was the problem for the color. I just deleted it, if it helps...